# Stripe Connect use setup_intent instead of payment_intent

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using `Stripe Connect` to charge on behalf a company

I'm using the test card `Authenticate unless set up 4000002500003155`.
I do a `Connect SetupIntent` first for future & `off_session` payments, between a company and the customer. Here's the parameters of the `Connect SetupIntent`

```
 $stripe->setupIntents->create(
 [
    'customer' => $stripe_customer_id,
    'payment_method' => 'card_1OP0hoJpAkZLjTfwYXsiJWOt',
    'automatic_payment_methods' => ['enabled' => true],
    'confirm' => true,      
    'usage' => 'off_session',
    'return_url' => $my_return_url  
 ],
 [
    'stripe_account' => $stripe_connected_account
 ]
 );
```

`$stripe` being an instance of

```
 \Stripe\StripeClient
```

I get a next_step with a return url of my choice, and finish the setup with return url. I get a `SetupIntent` `seti_1OP0hrJpAkZLjTfwahdJqJuy`

This is successful. Now I do a test payment with that card.

I thought I needed to pass the `SetupIntent` `seti_1OP0hrJpAkZLjTfwahdJqJuy` of the payment method to create a `Connect PaymentIntent` but it doesn't work.

```
No such PaymentMethod: 'seti_1OP0hrJpAkZLjTfwahdJqJuy'
```

I can only create a `Connect  PaymentIntent` with the `PaymentMethod` `card_1OP0hoJpAkZLjTfwYXsiJWOt` instead.

```
  $stripe->paymentIntents->create([
        'amount' => 1000,
        'currency' => 'cad',
        'customer'=> $stripe_customer_id,
        'application_fee_amount' => 123,
        'payment_method' => 'card_1OP0hoJpAkZLjTfwYXsiJWOt',
        'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
        'transfer_data' => [
            'destination' => $stripe_account
        ]
  ]);
```

When I use the `PaymentMethod` `card_1OP0hoJpAkZLjTfwYXsiJWOt` that already has a `SetupIntent`, and despite this card being `Authenticate unless set up`, and pass

```
confirm => false
```

Then there is no charge captured. Here are some relevant attributes of the returned `PaymentIntent`

```
 ["id"]=> string(27) "pi_3OivQsJpAkZLjTfw0MxC041u"
 ["object"]=> string(14) "payment_intent"
 ["amount"]=> int(1000)
 ["amount_capturable"]=> int(0)  
 ["amount_received"]=> int(0) 
 ["automatic_payment_methods"]=>  NULL,
 ...
```

If I set

```
confirm => true
```

I still get a `next_action` that I already got when doing the `SetupIntent`.

```
  ["status"]=> string(15) "requires_action",
  ["next_action"]=> object(Stripe\StripeObject)#244 (2) {
       ["type"]=> string(14) "use_stripe_sdk",
       ...
```

I don't quite understand why I still need to confirm the payment again, my understanding is creating a `SetupIntent` when registering a card with future payments & off session options is made for that case I'm describing. Is there something I'm missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only `off_session` payments on the card that was set up will be exempted from 3D Secure. On-session payments always require 3D Secure.
https://stripe.com/docs/testing#authentication-and-setup

> This card requires authentication for **off-session** payments unless you set it up for future payments. After you set it up, **off-session payments no longer require authentication.**

That is to simulate [this exemption category][1].

You need to pass `"off_session"=>true` when creating the PaymentIntent that charges the saved card.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm#confirm_payment_intent-off_session

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web&ui=elements#charge-saved-payment-method

[1]: https://stripe.com/guides/strong-customer-authentication#:~:text=the%20customer%E2%80%99s%20bank.-,Merchant%2Dinitiated%20transactions,-(including%20variable%20subscriptions